# Slow SSD performance

Tags: ssd, performance, storage, 20.10

I have a sata ssd which when I use on windows(dual boot) is just as advertised have a read write performace around 500MB/s, but on the other hand when I use it under ubuntu(20.4-20.10) write performace is just shy of 100MB/s, read performance is although OK. So, I thought maybe it was some magic of IO scheduler. Therefore, I decided to change it and even after creating a udev rule for sda with IO scheduler attribute "none"(tried also kyber, mq-deadline is default) there is no improvement at all. So, to dig down the problem I used `dd` with `iotop` monitoring to find out what was actually happening what I found was totally unexpected. It did went up to around 500MB/s for only for some small burst of time and except It never went more than 100 MB/s and even sometimes it just fell below 20 MB/s. And yes APM is disabled(255). Now I have no idea what should I do to improve SSD performance.

Here are some info:

```
$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda

/dev/sda:

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       TS240GSSD220S                           
    Serial Number:      F528440890          
    Firmware Revision:  R0510A0 
    Media Serial Num:   
    Media Manufacturer: 
    Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
    Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x0110) 
    Supported: 9 8 7 6 5 
    Likely used: 9
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   16383   16383
    heads       16  16
    sectors/track   63  63
    --
    CHS current addressable sectors:    16514064
    LBA    user addressable sectors:   268435455
    LBA48  user addressable sectors:   468862128
    Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Physical Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:      228936 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:      240057 MBytes (240 GB)
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
    Form Factor: 2.5 inch
    Nominal Media Rotation Rate: Solid State Device
Capabilities:
    LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
    Queue depth: 32
    Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
    R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 1   Current = 1
    Advanced power management level: disabled
    DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
         Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
    PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
         Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
    Enabled Supported:
       *    SMART feature set
            Security Mode feature set
       *    Power Management feature set
       *    Write cache
       *    Look-ahead
       *    Host Protected Area feature set
       *    WRITE_BUFFER command
       *    READ_BUFFER command
       *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
            Advanced Power Management feature set
            SET_MAX security extension
       *    48-bit Address feature set
       *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
       *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
       *    SMART error logging
       *    SMART self-test
       *    General Purpose Logging feature set
       *    WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
       *    64-bit World wide name
       *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
       *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
       *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
       *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
       *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
       *    Phy event counters
       *    READ_LOG_DMA_EXT equivalent to READ_LOG_EXT
       *    DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
            Device-initiated interface power management
       *    Software settings preservation
            Device Sleep (DEVSLP)
       *    SANITIZE feature set
       *    BLOCK_ERASE_EXT command
       *    DOWNLOAD MICROCODE DMA command
       *    WRITE BUFFER DMA command
       *    READ BUFFER DMA command
       *    Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 8 blocks)
       *    Deterministic read data after TRIM
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 65534
        supported
    not enabled
    not locked
        frozen
    not expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
    2min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 2min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 57c3548185201a3a
    NAA     : 5
    IEEE OUI    : 7c3548
    Unique ID   : 185201a3a
Device Sleep:
    DEVSLP Exit Timeout (DETO): 90 ms (drive)
    Minimum DEVSLP Assertion Time (MDAT): 26 ms (drive)
Checksum: correct
```

inxi -Fxz

```
$ inxi -Fxz
System:
  Kernel: 5.8.0-26-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.0 Desktop: N/A 
  Distro: Ubuntu 20.10 (Groovy Gorilla) 
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: Micro-Star model: X470 GAMING PLUS MAX (MS-7B79) v: 3.0 
  serial: <filter> UEFI: American Megatrends v: H.60 date: 06/11/2020 
CPU:
  Info: 6-Core model: AMD Ryzen 5 3600 bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen 2 
  L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
  flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm 
  bogomips: 86399 
  Speed: 3602 MHz min/max: N/A Core speeds (MHz): 1: 3602 2: 3596 3: 3600 4: 3567 
  5: 3520 6: 3498 7: 3585 8: 3587 9: 3614 10: 3613 11: 3844 12: 3498 
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] 
  vendor: Sapphire Limited driver: amdgpu v: kernel bus ID: 27:00.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: amdgpu,ati 
  unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
  OpenGL: 
  renderer: Radeon RX 570 Series (POLARIS10 DRM 3.38.0 5.8.0-26-generic LLVM 11.0.0) 
  v: 4.6 Mesa 20.2.1 direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590] 
  vendor: Sapphire Limited driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 27:00.1 
  Device-2: AMD Starship/Matisse HD Audio vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: snd_hda_intel 
  v: kernel bus ID: 29:00.4 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.8.0-26-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
  vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: r8169 v: kernel port: f000 bus ID: 22:00.0 
  IF: enp34s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.13 TiB used: 156.29 GiB (13.5%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Transcend model: TS240GSSD220S size: 223.57 GiB temp: 51 C 
  ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Toshiba model: HDWD110 size: 931.51 GiB temp: 38 C 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 188.22 GiB used: 51.75 GiB (27.5%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda5 
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 16.00 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) file: /swapfile
```

Update: I got it to be not frozen. and running `hdparm -I` afterwards gives ony one difference,,  that is now there is a asterisk(*) before APM feature set. I don't know what it means though

Comment: Do you have latest firmware for SSD? And are you mounting with noatime? You also show "frozen"? Use hdparm to unfreeze
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2317805
Info on freeze
https://partedmagic.com/secure-erase/

Comment: @oldfred, yeah my ssd has latest firmware installed. and my ssd is mounted with noatime option. But what I don't understand is how frozen state related to performance issue. but no problem I'll unfreeze this from your link

Comment: Search this site for "slow" "copy" and see others suggestions to fix the problem of system buffers filling up and dragging the system to a crawl.  nocache should stop the buffering of the input file(s), ionice/renice may help, and special cases may be improved with swap tweaking or scheduler changes. But output buffers still fill up, and slow things down.

Answer (score 1):

Do you trim your partitions? I think windows is doing it automatically but in ubuntu, you must do it yourself (it also can be done automatically, search and you'll find how).

```
sudo fstrim -v /
```

This will trim the partition mounted in `/`

Comment: I regularly trim my devices. And anyway I was even doing all the benchmarks in a fresh patition(of about 20 GB). So, there can be no possibility like that

Comment: This was the solution for me running into this problem.